# Ktor + Postgres - Exception: Function not implemented in LinuxWatchService

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, ktor, kotlin-exposed

I get the following exception when trying to startup my Ktor server:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Function not implemented
       at java.base/sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService.<init>(LinuxWatchService.java:64)
       at java.base/sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystem.newWatchService(LinuxFileSystem.java:47)
       at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$watcher$2.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:81)
       at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$watcher$2.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:79)
       at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
       at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.getWatcher(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:79)
       at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.cleanupWatcher(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:364)
       at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.start(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:281)
       at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationEngine.start(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:216)
       at io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(EngineMain.kt:23)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Jetbrains Exposed.

Due to a copy and paste error I had a duplicated field name defined in my table definition, as soon as I removed the duplicate field name the server started again.